# Creating array with from another array

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14

I would like to create an array from another array using a for loop. First array holds only number of employees and second array to holds women with dailyPeyment under ...
this is my main.cpp

```
void main() {
    int  womUnder=100, numOfEmp=0;
    char menu;
    CWorker* employee = new CWorker[womUnder];
    do {
        cout << "         MENU FOR ADDING EMPLOYEE:\n"
         << "1 - Add new employees: \n"
         << "2 - Show all employee: \n"
         << "3 - Names of the all men with salary over 400$: \n"
         << "4 - Names and birth dates of the all women with daily salary above 20$: \n"
         << "Chose 0 for end:";
        cin >> menu;

        switch (menu) {
        case '0': break;
        case '1': employee[numOfEmp++].setData(); break;
        case '2': for (int i = 0; i < numOfEmp; i++)employee[i].getData(); break;
        case '3': for (int i = 0; i < numOfEmp; i++)employee[i].menOver(); break;
        case '4': for (int i = 0; i < numOfEmp; i++)employee[i].womenUnder() ; break;
        default: cout << "\nERROR YOUR INPUT IS INCORRECT\n";
        }
    } while (menu != '0');
}
```

and this is my womenUnder function in class CWorker

```
void CWorker::setData() {
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "\tEnter name of the employee: \n"; getline(cin, name);
    cout << "Enter Personal Identity number: "; getline(cin, PIN);
    cout << "Enter daily peyment for the employee: "; cin >> dailyPayment;
    cout << "Enter work days for the employee: "; cin >> workDays;
}
void CWorker::getData() {
    cout << "\tName of the employee: " << name <<endl
     << "Personal id. number on the employee is: " << PIN << endl
     << "Daily payment for the employ1ee: " << dailyPayment << endl
     << "Work days for the employee: " << workDays ;
}
};
void CWorker::womenUnder() {
    int pinLastTwo, y, m, d;
    string lastS = PIN, lastString = lastS.substr(lastS.length() - 2, 2), year = PIN, mounth = PIN, day = PIN;
    istringstream(lastString) >> pinLastTwo;
    string yearByPin = year.substr(0,2), mounthByPin = year.substr(2, 2), dayByPin = year.substr(4, 2);
    istringstream(yearByPin) >>y;
    istringstream(mounthByPin) >> m;
    istringstream(dayByPin) >> d;
    
    
    if (dailyPayment < 20 && pinLastTwo %2 == 1) {
        cout << "\nWomen under 20$ daily peyment : " << string(name) << "\n Birthday Date:\n Year: " 
            << 1900+y << ", month: " << m << ", day: " << d << endl;
    }
```

Comment: don't use manual memory management (`new`, `delete` ) in C++. For arrays use `std::vector`

Comment: First, count the number of employees that fulfills those conditions. Then allocate memory for that many ``CWorker`` using ``new`` and copy the information.